# SASS, node-sass returns "Invalid UTF-8"

Tags: sass, node-sass

I have a very simple node-sass script:

```
var sass = require('node-sass');
var stats = {};
sass.render({
    file: "./src/sass/test.scss",
    outFile: "./src/css/test.css",
    success: function(css) {
        console.log(css);
        console.log(stats);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    },
    stats: stats
});

console.log(stats);
```

Which prints in the console:

```
{
  "status": 3,
  "message": "Invalid UTF-8",
  "code": 3
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve similar issue with a Sass Gulp task by removing the letter "ä" from my folder name. Maybe you have a UNIX unsupported letter in your folder path too? Try removing it.